# Unity/Firebase - Project Bundle ID does not match any bundle IDs in your google-services.json files

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

I'm making a mobile game on Unity, Android first.

And now I'm integrating firebase analytics.

After set info on Firebase Console and put `google-services.json` file into Unity project, Unity shows an error saying :

```
Project Bundle ID com.RetroSpirit.ToiletRush does not match any bundle IDs in your google-services.json files
This will result in an app that will fail to initialize.

Available Bundle IDs:


You need to either:
* Fix your app's bundle ID under "Player Settings --> Bundle Identifier"
or:
* Add another app to your firebase project
  Goto https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app_1
  and add the new configuration file to your project.

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Firebase.Editor.GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson:LogErrorIfEnabled(String)
Firebase.Editor.GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson:FindGoogleServicesFile(SortedDictionary`2, String, LogMessage, LogMessage)
Firebase.Editor.GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson:FindGoogleServicesFile(String, LogMessage, LogMessage)
Firebase.Editor.GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson:UpdateJson(Boolean, LogMessage, LogMessage)
Firebase.Editor.GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson:OnPostprocessAllAssets(String[], String[], String[], String[])
UnityEditor.AssetPostprocessingInternal:PostprocessAllAssets(String[], String[], String[], String[], String[])
UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility:ProjectWindowDrag(HierarchyProperty, Boolean)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Here's the part of `google-services.json`,

```
 "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "*:***********:android:****************",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.RetroSpirit.ToiletRush"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "***********-********************************.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "com.RetroSpirit.ToiletRush",
            "certificate_hash": "****************************************"
          }
```

I don't know what should I check.

Project Bundle ID (the Package name on Build Settings - Other Settings - Identification) is exactly same as package_names in `google-services.json`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little bit funny to answer myself...

I found the reason of problem accidently. There was something wrong with my VC runtime so `generate_xml_from_google_services_json.exe` couldn't extract package name from `google-services.json`. (vc90.crt.manifest could not be extracted!)

Unfortunately, I couldn't fix that runtime error despite so many re-install of Visual Studio, VC Runtime and .net frameworks. Finally I re-installed Windows 10 and the problem just gone away... Still don't know what caused this error.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you have fixed this by re-installing Windows but this is how I got passed this problem in case anyone else runs into this:

Make sure you have set your Package Name in Unity player settings (**Edit > Project Settings > Player > Other Settings > Identification > Package Name**).

Set to the same one you set up in Firebase (looks like com.CompanyName.ProductName).

Make sure you have imported the Firebase assets into your Unity project as described here https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup and that the Firebase folder exists in **Assets > Firebase**. Changing the location of this folder seems to break things.

Answer (score 1):

My case was in Unity and to fix it I added the google-services.json from the firebase project to the assets folder. I had only the GoogleService-Info.plist before.

Answer (score 0):

In our case we solved the issue by requesting a new google-services.json file from a collegue who has admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was with the Package Name. So I followed the following steps and solved the problem:

1. Change the package name (*com.companyname.appname*) [everything in lowercase]
2. Delete the existing keystore
3. Add a new keystore and generating a fingerprint with **Keytool**
4. Delete the current app from the Firebase console
5. Add a new app with the correct package name and the generated fingerprint
6. download `google-services.json` again and Import to **Unity** under the **Assets** folder

Done! It works!!

Answer (score 0):

hey everyone I found a fix to this issue I'm using mac pro m1

step to fix

- reinstall visual studio
- download Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Android from the visual studio website
- restart the project

and after that, it will fix